# How to know a Otto Subscriber is registered

Tags: android, otto

I am using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) by Square. My subscriber class is registered in the Activity / Fragment `onStart` and `onStop` methods.

However sometimes, I get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing event handler
>   for an annotated method. Is class EventListener registered?
>   at com.squareup.otto.Bus.unregister(Bus.java:289)

I am pretty sure my class is registered. Is there a method to know if this class is registered or not ?

```
// in a Fragment or Activity
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Bus bus = new Bus();
    bus.register(eventListener); // register the class where the annotated @Subscribe method is
    bus.isRegistered(); // ??
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @laalto said there is no such method in Bus API.
Here is how I implemented the boolean isRegistered

```
//  implement as a Singleton class
public class EventListener {

    // necessary to avoid to unregister a non-registered instance . Since EventListener is a Singleton
    private static boolean isRegistered;

    public void setIsRegistered(final boolean registered){
        isRegistered = registered;
    }

    public boolean isRegistered(){
        return isRegistered;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onTrackingEvent(final TrackingEvent event) {
        // to do
    }
}
```

Now in the Fragment or Activity, register/unregister to the `com.squareup.otto.Bus`

```
// in a Fragment or Activity
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // eventListener is the class containing the @Subscribe method
    bus.register(eventListener);
    eventListener.setIsRegistered(true);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (eventListener.isRegistered()) {
        bus.unregister(eventListener);
        eventListener.setIsRegistered(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You get this error message if you try to `unregister()` an object that has not been registered, or are unregistering twice.

Since registration is object-based, you can simply add a `boolean isRegistered` member to those classes where the usual lifecycle doesn't guarantee correct pairing of registers and unregisters.

Comment: Thanks @Iaalto, I already had this idea of boolean . But just wondering if the guys at Square made a special method

Comment: No, there's no such method in Bus API itself. Most of the time activity/fragment/service/whatever lifecycle guarantees register/unregister calls are paired. For the rare cases where that's not available, use the boolean in your class.

Answer (score 0):

as explained above, Otto's API doesn't provide a way to interrogate if a potential subscriber has registered with a `Bus` instance. the fail-fast semantics are designed to bring the fact that there is an unpaired call to `register()` and/or `unregister()` in your code to your immediate attention, rather than letting the condition linger further and lead to some potentially unexpected side effects later on.

while i agree with the approach, i recently found myself with little time to track down this problem in one of my own projects, so i implemented a quick and dirty little Kotlin-based hack using extension functions to give myself some breathing room. the below swallows the `IllegalArgumentExceptions` associated with duplicate registrations as well as attempts to unregister subscribers that haven't yet registered. it's pretty fragile and it'd be more performant to avoid the exception handling all together, but this at least requires less scaffolding to maintain the component's registration state:

```
fun Bus.registerSafely(`object`: Any) {
    try {
        this.register(`object`)
    } catch(t: Throwable) {
        when(t) {
            is IllegalArgumentException -> {
                val message = t.message

                if(message != null && message.contains("Object already registered", ignoreCase = true)) {
                    /* quietly ignore this... */
                } else {
                    throw t
                }
            }

            else -> throw t
        }
    }
}

fun Bus.unregisterSafely(`object`: Any) {
    try {
        this.unregister(`object`)
    } catch(t: Throwable) {
        when(t) {
            is IllegalArgumentException -> {
                val message = t.message

                if(message != null && message.contains("Missing event handler", ignoreCase = true)) {
                    /* quietly ignore this... */
                } else {
                    throw t
                }
            }

            else -> throw t
        }
    }
}
```